# Spring Cloud Stream (Kafka) producer with topic name identified at run time

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

My requirement is to publish messages to topics that are determined at run time. Hence I won't be able to mention my topic name in my application properties/yaml file.
Is there a way to handle this with SCS?

Comment: I guess your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485421/spring-cloud-stream-to-support-routing-messages-dynamically

Comment: @IlayaperumalGopinathan Did not understand the answer completely. Could you clarify my question in the pointed thread?

Comment: Hi @Ajay, can you please post the solution you adopted for this issue.